# Search Array using startsWith()

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for a bit of help searching within an array using startsWith().

I want the user to enter a first name, search the array, and if the first name matches, print: employee ID number, last name, first name.

If there are no matches, return a simple error message.

The code below searches through the array, prints the matching employees, but also continues to print the error message until it has looped through the whole array.

The output currently:

```
ID No: 2345 - Holt, Steve
ID No: 2345 - Molt, Steve
ID No: 2345 - Sholt, Steve
ID No: 2345 - Colt, Steve
No Matching employee records found!
No Matching employee records found!
No Matching employee records found!
No Matching employee records found!
...
```

How can I change it to only return matches, OR if not matches, only then return the error message.

Thanks for your help!

```
private static final Service [] employeeList = new Employee [10];
private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args){

                                    // First name / Last name / Employee Number

  final Employee FakeEmployee0 = new Employee("Steve", "Holt", "2345");
  final Employee FakeEmployee1 = new Employee("Steve", "Molt", "2111");
  final Employee FakeEmployee2 = new Employee("Steve", "Sholt", "245");
  final Employee FakeEmployee3 = new Employee("Steve", "Colt", "2222");
  final Employee FakeEmployee4 = new Employee("Steve", "Wolt", "25");
  final Employee FakeEmployee5 = new Employee("Boy", "Blue", "1");
  final Employee FakeEmployee6 = new Employee("Boy", "Wonder", "8999");
  final Employee FakeEmployee7 = new Employee("Boy", "George", "500");
  final Employee FakeEmployee8 = new Employee("Will", "Smith", "123");
  final Employee FakeEmployee9 = new Employee("Will", "Ferret", "23");      

  employeeList [0] = FakeEmployee0;
  employeeList [1] = FakeEmployee1;
  employeeList [2] = FakeEmployee2;
  employeeList [3] = FakeEmployee3;
  employeeList [4] = FakeEmployee4;
  employeeList [5] = FakeEmployee5;
  employeeList [6] = FakeEmployee6;
  employeeList [7] = FakeEmployee7;
  employeeList [8] = FakeEmployee8;
  employeeList [9] = FakeEmployee9;

// Search for employees by first name:

  private static void searchNames(){

    System.out.println("Enter employee's first name: ");
    String nameCheck = sc.nextLine();


    for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++){
        if (employeeList[i].getFirstName().startsWith(nameCheck)){
            System.out.println("ID No: " + employeeList[i].getIdNum() + " - "
                               + employeeList[i].getLastName() + " " +
                               employeeList[i].getFirstName());
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("No Matching employee records found!");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: use [`break;`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statement to stop the loop and place the else part outside the loop

Comment: can you please add the output that you're getting?

Answer (score 5):

The *problem* is in your `for` loop. You are essentially printing the error message for each employee which does not fit your description.

To solve this issue, you can simply have a boolean flag, call is `empFound` which is initially set to `false`. As you go through your employees, if a match is found, then you simply set `empFound` to true and `break` the loop.

Outside the `for` loop, you show the error message if and only if `empFound` is `false`.

As @vvs pointed out, the solution proposed here will stop once that you have found your match, that is, it will yield at most 1 hit. If you want to list all the employees which start with the string you are after, simply omit the `break` statement. This will cause the loop to keep going and check all your employee elements.

Comment: Breaking the loop is not essential, as it will cause the loop to break after just one match.

Comment: @vvs: `and if the first name matches` this is why I think that the `break` statement is required. I'll add a clarification to my answer.

Comment: I agree its not clear in the question whether 1 match is required or more. I agree with the edit made.

Comment: I´d rather use the boolean flag as additional condition for the loop instead of using the `break`. If the logic inside the loop will get more complex then the `break` statement might create some confusing results for the programmer.

Comment: @KevinEsche: That would also work. I opted for `break` simply because this seems to be an assignment, so I took the opportunity to try and introduce the OP to another keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the help! If there is no match, the loop still prints out 10 lines of "No matching employee..." How can I combat this?

Comment: @LachlanNorris: You need to remove the `else` part in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to print all employess that match thus break will not solve it.
What you should do is have a flag if you found at least one employee with given name.

```
boolean atLeastOneFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++){
    if (employeeList[i].getFirstName().startsWith(nameCheck)){
        System.out.println(...);
        atLeastOneFound = true;
    }
}
if (!atLeastOneFound) {
    System.out.println("No Matching employee records found!");
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help! If there is no match, the loop still prints out 10 lines of "No matching employee..." How can I combat this?

Comment: Your original for loop was doing this: If it matches, print it, if it doesn't print "no matching emp.". Thus every employee in the array caused one of these messages. You can see in my example that I don't have any "else" clause

Comment: Thanks, I actually discovered I had more my brackets incorrectly when editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using Java 8 streams:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee[] employees = {
            new Employee("Steve", "Holt", "2345"),
            new Employee("Steve", "Molt", "2111"),
            new Employee("Steve", "Sholt", "245"),
            new Employee("Steve", "Colt", "2222"),
            new Employee("Steve", "Wolt", "25"),
            new Employee("Boy", "Blue", "1"),
            new Employee("Boy", "Wonder", "8999"),
            new Employee("Boy", "George", "500"),
            new Employee("Will", "Smith", "123"),
            new Employee("Will", "Ferret", "23")
    };
    String prefix = scanner.nextLine();
    List<Employee> matches =
            Arrays.stream(employees).filter(e -> e.getFirstName().startsWith(prefix)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (matches.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No Matching employee records found!");
    } else {
        matches.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

If you can't use streams, you have to iterate over the array and build the `matches` list on your own.

I moved the

```
System.out.println("ID No: " + employeeList[i].getIdNum() + " - "
                           + employeeList[i].getLastName() + " " +
                           employeeList[i].getFirstName());
```

part into the `toString` method of the `Employee` class like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("ID No: %s - %s %s", id, lastName, firstName);
}
```

Thus we are able to write just `matches.stream().forEach(System.out::println);` to print all matching employees.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Unfortunately the restraints of the activity do not allow me to use this, but it is great knowledge for the future!

Answer (score -1):

Insert `break` statement in inside your if block as your for is executing untill the loop ends

```
if (employeeList[i].getFirstName().startsWith(nameCheck)){
            System.out.println("ID No: " + employeeList[i].getIdNum() + " - "
                               + employeeList[i].getLastName() + " " +
                               employeeList[i].getFirstName());
          break;
}
```

Comment: Inserting break will cause the code to only print the "first" match.

Comment: This will ouput `No Matching employee records found!` on each iteration until some value is found (or not).

Answer (score -2):

Declare a flag `isFound = false;`

Add a break :

```
if (employeeList[i].getFirstName().startsWith(nameCheck)){
                System.out.println("ID No: " + employeeList[i].getIdNum() + " - "
                                   + employeeList[i].getLastName() + " " +
                                   employeeList[i].getFirstName());
                 isFound = true;
                 break;
            }
```

And remove the error message from the loop.
Outside of the loop check :

```
if(isFound) {
// print message
}
```

Comment: @X.L.Ant Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Edited the anser